# Difference between two regex: @(samp|code)\{[^A-Z]+\} and @(samp|code)\{[^}]+\}?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am newbie in regexs. Can anyone help me figure it out?

I am not working any project just want to learn regex. I was looking from this site:

ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gawk-3.0.3/html_chapter/gawk_5.es.html

I had already tried online regex engines. Regex101 Regex Tester etc.

- Case 1->  regex is `@(samp|code)\{[^A-Z]+\}`. Text are
  `@code{dsadsaad}`, `@samp&dsad}`  this two text are matching but
  there is `\{` condition in regex how ?

  [https://imgur.com/a/iXUJ2Iy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qRkT.png)
- Case 2->  regex is `@(samp|code)\{[^}]+\}` text are same. In this
  one, only first one matches as I want -> `@code{dsadsaad}`

  [https://imgur.com/a/Bi8v6IX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDmMu.png)

`\{` means have to be `{` character.

The same expression `\{` is same in both but only the second one is working.

`[^}]` means anything except `}`.`[^A-Z]` means anything except capital letters.

How `[^}]` and `[^A-Z]` can change a situation that they are not relevant with themselves?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Different regexps mean different things to different tools with different options and different delimiters. Show whichever tool you are running using those regexps against some sample input and the expected output so we can help you.

Comment: This looks as a bug in your regex engine, only the first matches in both examples in my tests. Are you sure the string and regexes you have shown are exactly the ones you test in your code?

Comment: Try this: https://regex101.com/r/MGeyCy/1 No match for second string.

Comment: What that online tool thinks any given regexp means isn't necessarily the same as what any command line tool thinks it means in any given context. Having said that, what the OP has told us so far is generally impossible in any context I can think of so I expect the problem must exist in some other part of his code than he's shown us so far or he's just misunderstanding the results. We need a [mcve] to begin trying to help him debug it.

Comment: Your case 1 explanation is incorrect. That regex won't match your second string.

Comment: ok guys firstly thanks for replies and special thanks to downvotes :D I thought I was explanatory enough but it wasn't I'll update first entry with images. I am not working any projects just want to understand regex 'because they are very useful at anything relevant with strings
@PedroRodrigues

Comment: ok guys firstly thanks for replies and special thanks to downvotes :D I thought I was explanatory enough but it wasn't I'll update first entry with images. I am not working any projects just want to understand regex 'because they are very useful at anything relevant with strings @EdMorton

Comment: I hadn't downvoted you till I saw that comment, then I did, then I retracted it since I think you are at least trying to form a decent question. The problem with your question is you've tagged it with awk, and are using awk manual as your regexp reference but then you're running a different tool and asking why it doesn't do what you expect and you're including images instead of text, and no expected output, etc. It's a bit of a mess. See [ask] for what's required to get help on this site and pay particular attention to the part about providing a [mcve] (textual sample input, output, and code)

Comment: thanks anyway i'll remove the awk tag it was unnecessary @EdMorton

Comment: You'd be far better off leaving the awk tag but providing an awk [mcve]. See my answer for how to do that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can tell from the images you posted, your first regexp is matching the whole multi-line text, not each line of it one line at a time.

I say "best I can tell" because while you tagged your question with awk this has nothing to do with awk - you're asking how some online tool parses your input given your regexp, not how awk does that, and I'm not familiar with that tool so I'm just guessing at what the highlighting in the image you posted means.

If you want to learn how regexps work in awk then write regexps in awk, not in some completely different online tool that undoubtedly supports different regexp variations than awk does and parses it's input differently than awk does. For example:

Sample Input:

```
$ cat file
@code{dsadsaad}
@samp&dsad}
```

Expected Output:

```
record #1, [@code{dsadsaad}]
<@code{dsadsaad}>

record #2, [@samp&dsad}]
no match
```

Actual Output 1:

```
$ awk '
{
    input = "record #" NR ", [" $0 "]"
    if ( match($0,/@(samp|code)\{[^A-Z]+\}/) ) {
        output = "<" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ">"
    }
    else {
        output = "no match"
    }
    print input ORS output ORS
}
' file
record #1, [@code{dsadsaad}]
<@code{dsadsaad}>

record #2, [@samp&dsad}]
no match
```

Actual Output 2:

```
$ awk '
{
    input = "record #" NR ", [" $0 "]"
    if ( match($0,/@(samp|code)\{[^}]+\}/) ) {
        output = "<" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ">"
    }
    else {
        output = "no match"
    }
    print input ORS output ORS
}
' file
record #1, [@code{dsadsaad}]
<@code{dsadsaad}>

record #2, [@samp&dsad}]
no match
```

So all good so far, but now lets make awk read the whole file at once by setting the RS to null and see what we get:

Actual Output 3:

```
$ awk -v RS= '
{
    input = "record #" NR ", [" $0 "]"
    if ( match($0,/@(samp|code)\{[^A-Z]+\}/) ) {
        output = "<" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ">"
    }
    else {
        output = "no match"
    }
    print input ORS output ORS
}
' file
record #1, [@code{dsadsaad}
@samp&dsad}
]
<@code{dsadsaad}
@samp&dsad}>
```

Actual Output 4:

```
$ awk -v RS= '
{
    input = "record #" NR ", [" $0 "]"
    if ( match($0,/@(samp|code)\{[^}]+\}/) ) {
        output = "<" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ">"
    }
    else {
        output = "no match"
    }
    print input ORS output ORS
}
' file
record #1, [@code{dsadsaad}
@samp&dsad}
]
<@code{dsadsaad}>
```

Hopefully you can see that there's nothing wrong with the regexps, they're behaving exactly as they should, you're getting results you didn't expect because you expected the input to be processed one line at a time but the online tool you're running is apparently processing all lines at once which is why the regexps match different parts of the multi-line string.

Comment: why output is different at online regex tools?

Comment: There is no such thing as **"a regexp"**. There are BREs, EREs, PCREs, and probably other flavors. Every tool recognizes one of those types of regexp, and some tools recognize different ones when passed different options and some tools recognize one but can handle the metachars from another if they are escaped. Every tool has delimiters around the regexp and those delimiters if present in the regexp need to be escaped. Some tools support backreferences within regexps, others don't. Some versions of some tools support older/newer POSIX regexp specs. You need to consider the tool for a regexp.

Comment: Some tools read  one line of text at a time, others (with options) read paragraphs or whole files at a time. Some tools support POSIX character classes, some don't. Some support abbreviations for character classes, some don't. Some support word boundaries, some don't. etc. etc... And that's just the command line tools. So the questions isn't `why output is different at online regex tools?` - the output is different at **every** regexp tool.